# Scala: simple actor sending messages back to its sender

Tags: scala, actor

I'm very new to Scala and have been fiddling around with an `Actor`. I've written one that I would have expected would keep sending messages back and forth forever. But when I run it, `person1` sends a message that is successfully received by `person2`, but `person1` never gets the message back. (I only get one "Sending" and one "Responding".) I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something simple.

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

case object Hello

class Person() extends Actor {
  def talk(p:Person) {
    Console.println("Sending")
    p ! Hello
  }

  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case Hello => {
          Console.println("Responding")

          // This doesn't actually send a message back to the sender.
          sender ! Hello 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

object pingpong extends Application {
  val person1 = new Person
  val person2 = new Person
  person1.start
  person2.start
  person1.talk(person2)
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This works by explicitly passing the sender as part of the message, rather than using the `sender` method:

```
class Person() extends Actor {
  def talk(p:Person) {
    Console.println("Sending")
    p ! (Hello, this)
  }

  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case (Hello, theSender:Actor) => {
          Console.println("Responding")
          theSender ! (Hello, this)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is the problem just that I shouldn't be using `sender` like I was using it, or is there something else going on? Can one use `sender` to send a message to the sender?

Comment: Before you go any further with this, I should tell you that Scala actors are deprecated, and you should be using Akka actors (which are now the standard Scala actors).